# Certain mouse inputs are blocked for an amount of time after keyboard inputs (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse

If I make a keyboard input and then quickly try and make a mouse input, said mouse input will be blocked for an amount of time after keyboard inputs (Windows 7).

I have reproduced the problem with both wired USB devices and Wireless USB devices (Logitech wireless devices).

I have verified the problem occurs in different software applications:

- Web browser text editing
  *** For example if I hit Ctrl+B for bold then quickly select the next line of text that input will be blocked for about 1-2 seconds.**
- starcraft Brood War
- LibreOffice Writer

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated (except for recommending that I upgrade to windows 10)

Comment: Does this happen with notepad? Try it also when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Sometimes, on some laptops - mouse movement is blocked when using a trackpad to stop them interfering with each other - Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas This is a laptop. I use it with its lid closed, and attached to HDMI external monitor and USB devices, essentially I use it as a desktop.

Comment: @harrymc good thinking with safe mode. In safe mode the problem does not happen. The problem does occur on notepad. I wonder if the safemode making it go away points to a possible driver issue?

Comment: It likely points to some installed product. Examine the products that start with Windows.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you so much I am an idiot, for years this machine has had a utility called "TouchFreeze" installed, which is intended to prevent unwanted trackpad inputs when typing. This was the cause and disabling it solves the problem, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was an application called "TouchFreeze" which is useful if you have issues with unwanted inputs to a trackpad while typing, but is useless if you are using a keyboard mouse. Disabling the application solved the problem. It apparently just works by blocking all mouse input for a time after any keyboard input. Thanks to @harrymc for helping me to realize this.